# How to perform a penetration test with Nessus on a VPN internal service?

Tags: nessus

I did some penetration testing of services reachable by URL and managed to find some vulnerabilities I was looking for. However, now I should run tests for some services that are not reachable by URL, but rather by their IP inside the VPN.
I am connected to the VPN through NetExtender. Using the same configuration used in the URL case, the test ends immediately and produces no results. Is there any extra step that needs to be done? I would like to point out that I have full access to the VPN and can correctly ping the machine under test. This is the configuration I am using. In the case of services reachable by URL, I entered the URL instead of the IP and it worked.

[image]

[image]

The test ends like this.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the community. If I understand your problem correctly, have you tried setting an alias in a HOSTS file?

Comment: Thanks!!! I haven't done it, but I can try.

Comment: Did it work? Or is there any other issue you're having?

Comment: The URL was enabled for those machines as well, so I could use it to do the test. I may need it for more testing in the near future, though, and I will have a chance to test if it works.